# Restricting guest connections in QEMU virtual machine, how?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I run QEMU to emulate Windows KVM. I currently use `-net nic` with `-net user` to access WAN from guest, and this works like plain tunnel with no possibility to control connections, **add whitelist or restrictions**.

It is also dangerous setup due to the IP level packet forwarding, e.g. ports are open and all low-level connections on guest are possible. Say if i am running malware, such can function in nearly real networking environment.

<strike>Say i have running proxy **socks5://127.0.0.1:9050/** on host and my host Internet connection is `wlan0`. How can i force QEMU to use such proxy as networking adapter, is there any solution? So at least, i will use Tor for my guests for privacy.</strike>

I've managed to setup TAP networking adapter `virbr0` for my guest and enable it with command line `-netdev bridge,br=virbr0,id=net0 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0` (and allowed virbr0 in `/etc/qemu/bridge.conf`). Howerver, i don't have internet access with such bridge and don't actually understand how can i use `iptables` to restrict outgoing/incoming connections for my VM

Previous title: **Is there a way to convert SOCKS proxy to a network bridge interface?**

Answer (score 1):

This won't work. SOCKS is an application-level protocol, not a generic networking mechanism. If you desire to use a SOCKS proxy with an application, you'll need to ensure that the application supports using a proxy, and is configured to do so.

Comment: Seems theoretically real to write an application that will emulate networking interface using SOCKS proxy (with cutting any lower-level, unsupported traffic except DNS, TCP,UDP), i thought maybe someone did this ..

Comment: Sure, it's possible, but doing so would require a server-side component on the other side of the proxy to "un-wrap" and convert to the actual protocols.

Comment: Ok then . So the question is whats problem with my `virbr0` not giving internet access and can i control it with iptables.

Comment: That's a different question altogether.